# This is my code in MySQL.. I keep getting error #1064

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE 'temp_db'.'products' (id INT(6) NOT NULL, 
                                   name  VARCHAR(30), 
                                   category INT(30));
```

Please help.

Comment: Use sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: 1) Wrong quoting symbols (see provided answers). 2) `INT(30)` is illogical - this datatype cannot store such long value. Moreover, length specification for integer datatypes is already deprecated and ignored - so remove it at all for both INT columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks `` ` `` instead of single quotes `'`.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_db`.`products` (id INT(6) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(30), category INT(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks instead of single quotes and add one primary key in your database table.

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_db`.`products` (id INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
                                   name VARCHAR(30),
                                   category INT(30));
```

Refer to this for [Create Table in mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)